# Wrapping a series of elements between classes until it meets another class

Tags: jquery

I am trying wrap all content between class "product-category", with class "content". And stop wrapping when it meets class "end".

Given the markup:

```
<div class="product-category">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p>Quae aliquid, ex enim eveniet!</p>
    <p>Eligendi similique maxime, fugiat porro.</p>
</div>
<div class="product-category">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p>Quae aliquid, ex enim eveniet!</p>
    <p>Eligendi similique maxime, fugiat porro.</p>
</div>
<div class="end">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
```

What I want is to make it:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="product-category">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        <p>Quae aliquid, ex enim eveniet!</p>
        <p>Eligendi similique maxime, fugiat porro.</p>
    </div>
</div>  
<div class="content">
    <div class="product-category">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        <p>Quae aliquid, ex enim eveniet!</p>
        <p>Eligendi similique maxime, fugiat porro.</p>
    </div>
</div>  
<div class="end">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
```

I used .nextUntil, but don't know how to end it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [.wrap](https://api.jquery.com/wrap)

```js
$('.product-category').wrap('<div class="content" />')
```

```css
.product-category {
  background: lightblue;
}
.content {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-category">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  <p>Quae aliquid, ex enim eveniet!</p>
  <p>Eligendi similique maxime, fugiat porro.</p>
</div>
<div class="product-category">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  <p>Quae aliquid, ex enim eveniet!</p>
  <p>Eligendi similique maxime, fugiat porro.</p>
</div>
<div class="end">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
```

If you have `product-category` elements even after `end` element then

```
$('.end').prevAll('.product-category').wrap('<div class="content" />')
```